# How can I check whether Vim has the -p (tabs) option or not?

Tags: vim, alias, bashrc

I would like to figure out in my `.bashrc` (or one of the files it sources) whether Vim has the `-p` option available and if so create an alias.

Now, that same `.bashrc` is used on numerous systems including some ancient ones where Vim still doesn't know the `-p` option.

What I need is a way to check for the availability of the option without actually starting up Vim ...

```
vim -p || echo "Not available"
```

... where instead of the echo I do something else came to mind, but unfortunately that only works when the `-p` option is not available. When it is available, this will actually start up Vim, which is what I want to avoid.

I've experimented with opening `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero` to no avail ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ vim --help | grep "\-p"
   -p[N]        Open N tab pages (default: one for each file)
```

So why not use:

```
if [ -n "$(vim --help | grep "\-p")" ]; then 
    echo "set your option here";
fi
```

Comment: Well, because sometimes one is blind to such simple solutions ;) ... thanks a lot. Using basically: `vim --help|grep -q '[:space:]*-p' || echo test` now ... that seems to work (of course I am using something other than `echo` there).

Comment: In your example you need to use [[:space:]] and probably \+ instead of *. An alternate example: vim --help | grep -q '[[:space:]]\+-p' && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'